# Order of "show" changes ranges

Tags: plotting

I am trying to superimpose two plots: a ContourPlot and a LogLogPlot. Even though they both have the same range individually, when I "show" both of them, the range of one is wrong (depending on which plot comes first in "show").

Here are the plots:

```
pl1 = LogLogPlot[(5*10^15)/x, {x, 10^(-7), 10^(-3)}]
pl2 = ContourPlot[a^(-2/3)*b^-2, {a, 10^(-3), 10^(-7)}, {b, 10^8, 10^23}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10", "Log10"}]
```

Then when I run

```
Show[{pl1, pl2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

the two plots do not overlap even though they should. Running them in reverse order:

```
Show[{pl2, pl1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives a different (and also incorrect) result

Comment: Have you tried setting `PlotRange->All` individually in both original plots?

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. They give the same result

Comment: @J.M. that I had not seen. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Show` command uses the options from the first graphic that you feed to it, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

This explains why when you are re-ordering the graphics you get different results. It is to be expected.

In order to fix that: since, show knows what it is doing just don't use the `PlotRange` command.

The following piece of code

```
pl1 = Plot[(5*10^15)/x, {x, 10^(-7), 10^(-3)}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, White}]; 
pl2 = ContourPlot[1/(a^(2/3)*b^2), {a, 10^(-3), 10^(-7)}, {b, 10^8, 10^23}, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10", "Log10"}]; 
Show[pl2, pl1]
```

gives

[image: plot]

Is this what you wanted?